# How can I check if Google Cloud is logged in with Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-kms

If I log in to Google Cloud with `gcloud-init`, it appears that everything is successful. But I also want to check programmatically if I am successfully authenticated, and if not, halt the program. I tried the following code, which I thought was working and outputs the project ID to the console:

```js
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';

async function checkGoogleAuth() {
  try {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms',
    });
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    console.log(`  Google Auth Project ID: ${projectId}`);
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new Error(`Google Auth Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use the `@google-cloud/kms` library, I get the error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.

To get it to work, I need to execute:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

How can I check programmatically if I am successfully authenticated with Google Cloud and that the credentials can be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I was able to figure it out. Instead of importing `google-auth-library`, you can import `@google-cloud/kms` and attempt to get the project ID and the access control policy. Both of these throw errors if they fail.

```js
import KMS from '@google-cloud/kms';

async function checkGoogleAuth() {
  try {
    const kms = new KMS.KeyManagementServiceClient();

    const projectId = await kms.getProjectId();

    const formattedResource = kms.keyRingPath(
      process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID || '',
      process.env.GCLOUD_KMS_LOCATION || '',
      process.env.GCLOUD_KMS_KEY_RING || ''
    );
    await kms.getIamPolicy({
      resource: formattedResource,
    } as any);

    console.log(`  Google Auth Project ID: ${projectId}`);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(`Google Auth Error: ${err.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```